# how to restrict number of records to create

Tags: odoo

Is there any way to restrict the number of records to be created for a single object or table

My requirement needs me to create only 3 contacts for my company. Is there any way to do so.

```
Thanks & Regards,
Atchuthan
```

Comment: do you need to create only 3 company in OpenERP??

Comment: no only 3 contacts for a particular company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any one of the following method to restrict the number of records created.

```
1. Restrict from postgresql-- I dont know how to implement this
2. Restrict from python side.: Override your create method of your model and add check condition, if the limit is reached, then raise a warning.
```

For example, if you want to only to create max 5 users, then inherit `res.users` model,

```
class users(osv.osv):
    _inherit="res.users"
    def create(cr, uid, default, context=None):
        res = super(user, self).create(cr, uid, default, context)
        if len(self.search(cr, uid, [])) > 5:
            raise osv_except('Error','User Limt exceeded')
        return res
```

Comment: can you provide me detail regarding `create method in python`

Answer (score 0):

By default the limit is 80, however you can change this within this file:

```
web/addons/web/static/src/js/view_list.js
```

Full documentation on how to do it is at this website:

http://help.openerp.com/question/6627/how-set-limit-for-number-records-of-x2many/

Comment: If we change this value, it will affect other tables also but the limit should be changed only for a specific table and not other tables